# jQuery UI Tab returns first tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I've an asp:Button control in tabs-2. I'm inserting database something in onClick method, then it returns first tab but i want to open current tab. Also, page must be reload. How can i do ?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddContactKnowledge" CssClass="ButtonDefault" runat="server"    Text="add"  OnClientClick="ValidateContactKnowledge();" Width="120px" OnClick="btnAddContactKnowledge_Click" />
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you get and what you want?

Comment: I want to do something in button onClick Method, it musn't be post back. It shows current tab.

Comment: Did you try to strip your OnClick attribute using only OnClientClick? It won't cause a page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [cookie persistence feature](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie) of the JQuery UI Tabs widget.  Enabling cookie persistence will cause the tab that was last selected to be selected automatically when the page is reloaded.